# Regex throwing exception in JAVA, working in PHP

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

i have a working PHP regex which is

```
\w+[\(](\?*)\w+[\,](\?*)\w+[\)]
```

the link for its working is provided here https://regex101.com/r/tB2pS3/1

i am able to use it in PHP as intended but when i use the same in JAVA, it gives me exception that

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unknown inline modifier near index 37 (?<A>\w+\((\?*)\w+(,(\?*)\w+)?\))(,(?&A))*
```

i am not well versed in regex and java, but what i got is that there maybe some support issue after reading some related question on internet, as the regex is working fine and it gives accurate result in PHP, the problem is in JAVA some where.

help is needed in this regard.

Comment: Java regex does not support recursion and subroutine calls, `(?&A)` is invalid. Just replace with the A group pattern. And do not forget to use double backslashes to escape regex metacharacters in Java string literals. See [`"(\\w+\\(\\?*\\w+(?:,\\?*\\w+)?\\))(,\\w+\\(\\?*\\w+(?:,\\?*\\w+)?\\))*"`](https://regex101.com/r/tB2pS3/2).

Comment: i replaced my regex with ur ones, it is not throwing exception but not finding the patterns as well. any how i got the lead let me work out it. thanks for ur time and effort.

Comment: I removed the inner capturing groups, do you need them? Just put them where they were.

Comment: i am not getting it working, i am spilitting it into chunks and will try to find it by parts using two regex that are java compatible

Comment: Wait a sec, I will share come code

Comment: i really feel bad wasting your time

Comment: See http://ideone.com/CET4bS - does it do what you need?

Comment: Thanks a lot, u saved my day. The best

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Java regex does not support **recursion** and **subroutine calls**, `(?&A)` is invalid here. Also, do not forget to use double backslashes to escape regex metacharacters in Java string literals.

The only wayout is to repeat the `(?<A>)` group pattern at the end, see [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/tB2pS3/2):

```
(?<A>
  \w+\(
  \?*\w+
  (?:,\?*\w+)?
  \)
)
(,
  \w+\(
  \?*\w+
  (?:,\?*\w+)?
  \)
)*
```

I'd suggest a block-building method here, when you define the block first, and then build a dynamic pattern:

```
String block = "\\w+\\(\\?*\\w+(?:,\\?*\\w+)?\\)";
String pat = "(" + block + ")(," + block + ")*";
List<String> strs = Arrays.asList("a(b)", "a(?v)", "a(b),c(?c,a)");
for (String str : strs) {
    Matcher m = Pattern.compile(pat).matcher(str);
    while (m.find()) {
        System.out.println(m.group(0));
    }
}
```

See the [Java demo](http://ideone.com/CET4bS). I removed the inner capturing groups since most probably you are not going to use them anyway.